# Html.Action - InsufficientExecutionStackException

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

When i use  `@Html.Action("Index")` the `InsufficientExecutionStackException` is throw, why? it's a simple mvc command line.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`@Html.Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703457%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) is executing the action specified and returning the result of that action as a string.

If you are re-rendering the `Index` action that then re-renders this same view, its just going round and round and round.

If you want a link, use `@Html.ActionLink("Index")` instead.

Here is an example of this occurring:

```cs
public class HomeController : Controller
{
   public ViewResult Index()
   {
      return View();
   }
}
```

And this is the Razor code:

```html
<html>
<head>
   <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Causes an infinite loop; embedding the same action inside itself -->
    @Html.Action("Index")
</body>
</html>
```